# Trying to move data from csv to a template

Tags: microsoft-excel, automation

I have this time-sheet app that can output a csv file (with my check-in and out with project name and comments) that I would like to copy come row into the template used at my job.

For example, the template should always have the same 2 row (my name, formula for total time and column title) and export column 1, 2, 4 and 6  of the csv file to column 2, 3, 4 and 7 starting at row 3 in the time-sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double import the data from csv file during unwanted columns

Twice import the data from csv file, skip unwanted columns

[image: Double import the data from csv]

Comment: double? during unwanted column?
And yea, I know how to copy paste, I'm more thinking about a script that would do it, something I could prepare once and it would do it faster the next time

Comment: @matmat07 Import data is not copy-paste ... Create a template, where you get the data from csv file and use it. Change CSV - autochange data in open excel file.

Comment: Played with the settings and it seems to work thanks